# Rails remote form loaded via Ajax after document ready is not submitting

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a remote form using `form_tag` and `:remote => true` that is loaded from a partial. When I load the form through its own view as normal, it works as intended. However, then I try loading the partial on another page through AJAX after document ready. When I try to submit this form, nothing happens. I've tried a regular submit button and calling `form.submit()`.

Is there some javascript initialization to remote forms that Rails does that I have to duplicate? Or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think of off the top of my head is the CSRF token left out of the form.