# Rails remote link not working when loaded via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, link-to

I guess this question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548852/rails-remote-form-loaded-via-ajax-after-document-ready-is-not-submitting), but asking again as it has not yet been answered.

In my rails application, I have a view that contains a list of links that load content via ajax.

Here is the partial for the link

```
<%= link_to(story.title, {:controller=>"story", :id=>story.id}, :remote => true , :method=>'get', :class=>'story-link') %>
```

This remote link works fine and loads content via AJAX when the view is loaded via HTTP.

The view also has a small remote form which upon submission results in a new link added to the view. However, as this new link is loaded via AJAX, it does not work (i.e. does not load content via AJAX).

Moreover, when I refresh the view in the browser the new link works fine. I believe that the appropriate event binding does not take place when the link is loaded via AJAX. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to use [delegated event handling](http://www.iexposure.com/2012/10/26/rails-4-turbolinks-and-delegated-event-handling-in-jquery) for the form submission js, or re-register the form submission event(s) when the content is reloaded.

Comment: I am a newbie to web development, so I do not fully understand your answer. I am not having a form. Rather I have links. How do I re-register? For the links loaded as part of the view via HTTP, the `:remote=>true` automatically registers the appropriate events on the links, I believe!