# Multiple form loaded in view (index page) via Datatables - remote forms will not submit properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a Rails app with Datatables.  I am trying to add a select to each row that completes a simple JS call to update the record.  I started with adding:

`onchange: "this.form.submit();"`

to my selects.  This works EXCEPT the form does not respect the `remote: true` option for the form:

```
<form class="edit_flag" id="edit_flag_52" action="/myurl/path/id" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
<select name="name" id="id_1" onchange: "this.form.submit();`" class: "myclass"><option value="">n/a</option>
<option value="10">Steve</option>
<option value="4">Joe</option>
<option value="9">Frank</option>
<option selected="selected" value="55">Dan</option></select>
</form>
```

The '/myurl/path/id.js' loads in the browser vs remote.  After some searching is seems that because the forms are loaded via AJAX that causes this issue.  I have read about `binding` the events etc. - JS is not my strong skill so looking for some pointers here.  Here are the links I have found:

- [Rails: cannot submit a remote form that was loaded via Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613939/rails-cannot-submit-a-remote-form-that-was-loaded-via-ajax)
- [Rails remote link not working when loaded via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078950/rails-remote-link-not-working-when-loaded-via-ajax)

The main issue I have is that my view has multiple forms on the same page.

I tried this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.myclass', function() {
  this.form.submit();
});
```

This still has the same problem where the form does not submit remote.

**UPDATE**

Perhaps I am missing something here - I added a plain old submit button.  This method works as expected.  The form submits in the background.  I even added a call in my update.js.erb file that reloads the datatable (which was my plan once I got the select working).

Answer (score 0):

Ended up stumbling across this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('change', '.myclass', function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
  });
});
```

It works - not sure why. Hope this helps someone else.  Would accept another answer that explains why this works vs. what I had before.